# Count rows with 1 or more NaNs in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, nan

I have the following:

```
print(df.isna().sum())
```

Which gives me:

```
city                 2
country              0
testid               0
house             1807
house_number       248
po_box            1845
zipcode            260
road               132
state                1
state_district    1817
suburb            1800
unit              1806
```

I want the total number of rows that have 1 or more `NaN` values from columns `city, state, zip, and house`

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would use `isna` and `sum`:

```
cols = ['city', 'state', 'zip', 'house']
df[df[cols].isna().sum(axis=1) > 0]
```

---

Another option is calling `dropna` and checking the length.

```
u = df.dropna(subset=['city', 'state', 'zip', 'house'])
len(df) - len(u)
```