# pandas or numpy - how to count true/false array returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe called `result`:

```
find_a  id     find_b  id
yes     0001   yes     0001
no      0002   yes     0002
no      0003   no      0003
yes     0004   no      0004
yes     0005   yes     0005
```

I have the following:

```
result.find_a.values==find_b.values
```

Which retuns an array of True/False:
`array([ True, False, True, False, True])`

How do I build on this and get a count of `True`? If I can get the count, I can then later get a percentage of matched records between the columns, ie. `find_a` matched with `find_b` 40% of the time.

Also, I'm not sure if I am venturing down the numpy or pandas route...

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `np.count_nonzero`.  Since `True/False` are treated as 1/0, `sum` also works.

Comment: Hey, I noticed you unaccepted the answer below, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54205572/4909087). Would you let me know if there's anything wrong with them so I can fix it?

Comment: @coldspeed Ummmm not sure how that happened, user error maybe. Everything worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are dealing with large amounts of data, it really does not matter whether you use NumPy or pandas. Since you're using pandas, I would recommend just sticking to the basics unless you know you need otherwise.

To answer your original question, you can get the % of `True` values using `mean`:

```
(df['find_a'] == df['find_b']).mean()
# 0.6
```

Where,

```
df['find_a'] == df['find_b']

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len(result[result.find_a == result.find_b])
np.mean(result.find_a == result.find_b)
```